# define a dynamically-evaluated formula for a local variable

Tags: c#, expression

I was looking at a piece of error handling code that looks like this:

```
if (condition) {
    thereIsAProblem = true;
    problemDescription = "x";
}

if (!thereIsAProblem && condition2) {
    thereIsAProblem = true;
    problemDescription = "y";
}
```

And I got to wondering whether there is a way to define a local variable called `thereIsNotAProblem` that is dynamically based on the value of `thereIsAProblem`.  In other words:

```
var thereIsAProblem = false;
var thereIsNotAProblem = *** some expression... ***

Console.WriteLine(thereIsNotAProblem);   // true
thereIsAProblem = true;
Console.WriteLine(thereIsNotAProblem);   // false

if (thereIsNotAProblem && condition3) {
  ..
}
```

Is there some expression that can be entered on the line above that would assign the value of `thereIsNotAProblem` to be a dynamic formula based on `!thereIsAProblem`, and still allow `thereIsNotAProblem` to be supplied anywhere a `bool` value is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite... but you could make it a delegate instead:

```
Func<bool> thereIsNotAProblem = () => { /* some expression */ };

Console.WriteLine(thereIsNotAProblem());   // true
thereIsAProblem = true;
Console.WriteLine(thereIsNotAProblem());   // false
```

Note how now each time was want to evaluate `thereIsNotAProblem` we invoke the delegate... which evaluates the expression to get a `bool` value.

Comment: I suspected that was the only solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can do this by declaring a lambda,

```
var thereIsAProblem = false;
Func<bool> thereIsNotAProblem = () => !thereIsAProblem;
```

I'd argue you shouldn't. `thereIsAProblem` and `thereIsNotAProblem` look very similar and so one could easily be misread for the other. the use of `!` to negate a variable with a positive name is well understood and easy to read and should lead to less bugs.

I'd further argue that a better solution is the "fail fast" approach of returning as soon as there is a problem, avoiding the need to test for an earlier problem in the first place:

```
if (condition) 
{
    problemDescription = "x";
    return;
}

if (condition2) 
{
    problemDescription = "y";
    return;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use do something like the following 
(also see on .NET Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/E9X6XJ )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YourQuestion() returns " + YourQuestion());
        Console.WriteLine("AnswerOne() returns " + AnswerOne());
        Console.WriteLine("AnswerTwo() returns " + AnswerTwo());
    }

    private static bool condition1()
    {
        return false;
    }

    private static bool condition2()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static bool condition3()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public static string YourQuestion() 
    {
        var thereIsAProblem = false;
        var problemDescription = "";        

        if (condition1()) {
            thereIsAProblem = true;
            problemDescription = "x";
        }

        if (!thereIsAProblem && condition2()) {
            thereIsAProblem = true;
            problemDescription = "y";
        }

        return problemDescription;
    }

    public static string AnswerOne() 
    {
        return checkCondition1() ??
               checkCondition2() ??
               checkCondition3();
    }   

    private static string checkCondition1()
    {       
        return condition1() ? "x" : null;       
    }

    private static string checkCondition2()
    {       
        return condition2() ? "y" : null;
    }

    private static string checkCondition3()
    {       
        return condition3() ? "z" : null;           
    }


    public static string AnswerTwo()
    {       
        var conditionChecks = new Dictionary<string,Func<bool>>();
        conditionChecks.Add("x",condition1);
        conditionChecks.Add("y",condition2);
        conditionChecks.Add("z",condition3);
        foreach (var check in conditionChecks)
        {           
            if (check.Value())
            {
                return check.Key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: These show different design options that may lead you down a better path to the one you are currently following.  See Design Patterns.